# Fill background outside window QT

Tags: c++, css, qt

I have read a documentation and aswell many sites on website.
Unfortunatly I didn't find answer to my question.

Is there any chance(I believe there is) to fill background outside the popup window? Let me explain: If i have window like of my whole app with resolution 500x500 [px] and I create a popup window 300x300 in the middle - it means I have 200 px in each side "parent-window". Is there any chance (method, flag) to fill background in gray color?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W58jr.jpg

Comment: provide [mcve], plus an image that shows what you want would be very helpful.

Comment: I did put an image trying to explain what I want to get. 
So is there any flag or trick that gives me my target? If so what I need to do to get it ?

Comment: you can show the code with which you create the window and the popup, that's what I mean with [mcve]

Comment: @AnthonyMartial Aside from the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), can you also specify which OS / platform are you working with? Usually this kind of effects are handled by the window manager.

Comment: I am using QT 4.8 .

Comment: I am using QT 4.8 . Imagine that: You press some button in any site and you've got ask like: are you sure you want to do this and that. And this question is in the middle of screen(center) and everything what is "parent window" or under this popup window (whatever you call it) is like gray/black you don't really see it now because this popup window is most important now. You got it? And I want to make this effect but don't really know how.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the palette does the job. Here you get a purple background when the MessageBox is shown , and come back to normal once clicked

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPalette>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;

    QVBoxLayout mainLayout;
    QLabel foolabel("FooLabel");
    QPushButton foobutton("FooButton");
    mainLayout.addWidget(&foolabel);
    mainLayout.addWidget(&foobutton);
    QWidget window;
    window.setLayout(&mainLayout);
    w.setCentralWidget(&window);

    QPalette palette = QApplication::palette(&w);
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Inactive,QPalette::Window,QColor(138,43,226));
    w.setPalette(palette);

    w.show();

    QMessageBox box(&w);
    box.exec();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank You @sandwood, You saved my day. Appreciate that. It works. Have a nice day :)